# How does java.util.Arrays handle sorting an ArrayList (length vs size)?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've been looking through the source code for java.util.Arrays and when sorting it always refers to the length of the array (which for an ArrayList I assume refers to the length of the E[] data (transient) field.
But shouldn't it actually refer to the size field, given that they aren't always equal to each other.

Comment: As you have already been digging into that source, why not post some of it? There is more than one version of the JDK out there, so who knows that we would be all looking at the source code you peeked into?!

Comment: `Arrays` has nothing to do with sorting `ArrayList`, are you thinking of `Collections`?

Answer (score 1):

> when sorting it always refers to the length of the array

No it doesn't. For every datatype there is an overload of `Arrays.sort` which accepts `fromIndex` and `toIndex` parameters, specifying the exact portion of the array to sort, such as [`Arrays.sort(Object[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-int-int-java.util.Comparator-).

That is the method called by [`ArrayList.sort`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/80280d8b40e9/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l1452):

```
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    final int expectedModCount = modCount;
    Arrays.sort((E[]) elementData, 0, size, c);
    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
    modCount++;
}
```

The `ArrayList` passes its own `size` variable directly to the sorting method.

For a `List` which does not override [its `sort` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-), the [default implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/80280d8b40e9/src/share/classes/java/util/List.java#l476) first dumps the contents to a temporary array and sorts that:

> The default implementation obtains an array containing all elements in this list, sorts the array, and iterates over this list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array. (This avoids the n2 log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in place.)

```
default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    Object[] a = this.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) c);
    ListIterator<E> i = this.listIterator();
    for (Object e : a) {
        i.next();
        i.set((E) e);
    }
}
```

Beginning in Java 8, the old method [`Collections.sort(list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) just invokes `list.sort(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in `Collections`, it calls `toArray()` which returns an array of the ArrayList whose length is equal to the size, `Arrays` sorts the copy and `Collections` uses that to sort the actual ArrayList.